# Monte Carlo Method not accurate

Tags: java, math, pi

In celebration of [Pi Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Day), I decided to implement the [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) to approximate the value of [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi), but my algorithm doesn’t seem to be working.

I've tried running with different parameters, but I always get approx 3.66

I've tried debugging but I can't figure it out.

```
public class ApproximatePi {

    private int iterations; // how many points to test
    private double r; // width of the square / radius of circle (quarter circle)

    private int inCount = 0; // number of points that are inside the circle
    private int outCount = 0; // number of points outside of the circle

    private Random getNum = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    ApproximatePi(int iterations, double r) {
        this.iterations = iterations;
        this.r = r;
        // getNum = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public double getApproximation() {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            double x = (r) * getNum.nextDouble();
            double y = (r) * getNum.nextDouble();
            if (inside(x, y)) {
                inCount++;
            } else
                outCount++;
        }
        double answer = (double) inCount / (double) outCount;
        return answer;
    }

    private boolean inside(double x, double y) {
        // if the hypotenuse is greater than the radius, the point is outside the circle
        if (getHypot(x, y) >= r) {
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }

    private double getHypot(double x, double y) {
        double s1 = Math.pow(x, 2);
        double s2 = Math.pow(y, 2);
        return Math.sqrt(s1 + s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Pi *is* 2.41. It was shown in year 2355 by group of mathematicians that the previously believed 3.14 was false. Where have you been the past centuries?

Comment: I guess I didn't get the memo. I didn't realize it was safe to return to the surface again

Answer (score 5):

So, lets assume that radius is 1, so in this case what actually you're doing:

1. Generate bunch of x,y coordinates within square with coordinates `(0,0) - (1,1)`
2. Then you test which of them are within circle with center at `(0,0)`
3. By counting in/out counters you're getting how many points within circle's segment and how many outside

`inCount / (inCount+outCount)` represents ratio between in points to total surface

`r²` is total surface

Thus, you can get approximate area of 1/4th of circle via formula `inCount / (inCount+outCount) * r² == pi * r² / 4`

Now, you can say that `4 * inCount / (inCount+outCount) == pi`

Comment: Thank you! I was even thinking in my head "pi*r^2/r^2, so r^2 cancels out and I get pi" - Idk what my brain was doing.